# Accordion-Ux.layout.accordion list data does not show sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am using accordion layout, the data from the store loading fine for the collapsed items and we can see when it is expanded but for the items collapse: false,data is not loading.It is working fine on Firefox,but not working on Chrome and iOS simulator Can anyone please help me on this issue. I am using latest sencha touch version 2.2.1

here is my code

```
 config: {
     title: 'Check out',
     iconCls: 'truck',
     layout: {
             type: 'accordion',
             toggleOnTitlebar: true,
             mode: 'MULTIPLE',

     },
     scrollable: 'vertical',
     items: [{
             itemId: 'cartitems',
             title: 'Cart Items List',
             height: 600,
             layout: 'fit',
             collapsed: false,
             items: [{
                     xtype: 'list',
                     scrollable: {
                             direction: 'vertical',
                             directionLock: true
                     },
                     itemTpl: '<div class="cartitemlist">{DESCRIPTION} Item ID:{REDID} Price:{Price}</div>',
                     store: 'CartStore'
             }]
     }
```

data is showing up if the collapsed : true .. but it is not working when collapsed: false

Comment: post relevant code also. Without showing any code you'd hardly get any help.

Comment: Added the code.Would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a height to the list view.  E.g.

```
items: [{
                 xtype: 'list',
                 height: 500,
                 scrollable: {
                         direction: 'vertical',
                         directionLock: true
                 },
                 itemTpl: '<div class="cartitemlist">{DESCRIPTION} Item ID:{REDID} Price:{Price}</div>',
                 store: 'CartStore'
         }]
```